# What is the line $y=x$ and $y=-x$ called?

Tags: terminology, graphing-functions

I know that some non-english mathematicians use **first median** to mean the identity line $y=x$ (i.e. line considered in $\mathbb R^2$) and **second median** to mean the line $y=-x$. I don't suppose this is the same in English. Any special name for $y=-x$? Is identity line the only name for $y=x$?

Comment: The Identity Line

Comment: For the record, I've never heard of any have a name for these lines. $y=x$ or $y=-x$ seem to suffice.

Comment: In greek terminology , $y = x$ is called the bisector of the angle of the first and third quadrant, if this is sufficient.

Comment: I've seen $y=kx$ called *ratio lines* a few times, so that would make $y=x$ the *equality ratio line* or the *equality line* or *line of equality*.

Answer (score 2):

The terms *diagonal* and *anti-diagonal* are descriptive and "culturally apt".

The [first](http://planetmath.org/DiagonalEmbedding) is standard in geometry and topology (the *diagonal embedding* of a topological space $X$ is the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow X \times X$ defined by $x \mapsto (x, x)$), and I'm almost positive I've seen the second in connection with the normal bundle of a diagonal embedding of a manifold.

In a casual web search, the primary  usage of "anti-diagonal" refers to [square matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) for which entries are zero unless the row and column indices are "opposites" (specifically, $a_{ij} \neq 0$ only if $j = n + 1 - i$), but even this usage suggests the line $y = -x$ by association.